# Problema Conexao DB

Tags: c#, sql, microsoft-access

Estou fazendo um sistema em C#, conectei o banco dados (Access) e o programa pediu pra copiar o banco de dados pra pasta do sistema e tudo mais.

O problema é que a aplicação não está salvando os dados no banco da pasta do sistema, tenho que direcionar o banco no **App.Config**.

Como faço Isso?

Arquivo **App.Config**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="BancodeDados.Properties.Settings.BancodeDadosConnectionString"
            connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\GlimaSoftDB.mdb"
            providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Você tem como explicar melhor? Não dá pra entender nada.

Comment: Acredito que basta remover a parte |DataDirectory|\ da *connectionString*. Ficaria assim: `Source=GlimaSoftDB.mdb`. Entendo que desta maneira ele considera o diretório local do executável (se é a isso que você se refere como "pasta do sistema") como sendo o local do arquivo de banco de dados .

Comment: kkkk.
seguinte, na aplicação que eu fiz, quando vou cadastrar um USUÁRIO por exemplo, na parte de cadastro funciona normal, mais se eu fechar e abrir a aplicação, os dados nao fica salvo no banco de dados.
o banco de dados fica na pasta "DEBUG" do projeto.

Comment: li sobre algo a respeito e vi que o problema pode ser pq a aplicação nao esta apontada para o banco de dados da pasta q a aplicação esta, mas que tem como direcionar pra ele pelo App.Config, so ainda noa sei como fazer.